# Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't use my nVidia GT540M

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia-graphics-card

I got a problem with my laptop with Ubuntu 12.04. It has an nVidia GT540M video card which uses Optimus, which I want to use under Ubuntu. So far I tried:

1. Installing the official nVidia drivers.
2. Added the x-swat and Bumblebee repositories (as described here in the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation))
3. Tried to change xorg.conf manually.

Nothing has worked. Any clues?

Comment: the question does not belong on SO. It belongs to askubuntu.com. When posting there add details: your xorg.conf, exact error messages, relevant parts of /var/log/Xorg.0.log.

Comment: Hi, sry for that some ppl on the Ubuntu IRC told my i should post it here, thats why iam landed here, as u can see iam not confirm with Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you running your 3D apps with `optirun`? The `ubuntu-x-swat` repo shouldn't be needed for 12.04.